# TS2339 : Property totalPages doesnt exist on type Object

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-services

i'm working in a simple application with angular5 , i have a page which returns the lists of some projects information using an API Restful with spring boot .

everything goes well , but i can't get that working while trying to use Pagination following a tutorial in youtube .

this is the method where i get an error

```
        pageProjects:any;
        pages:Array<number>;

    ngOnInit() {

        this.projetSevice.getProjects(this.currentPage,this.size)
          .subscribe(data=>{
            this.pageProjects=data;
            this.pages=new Array(data.totalPages);
          },err=>{
            console.log('this is error');
          })
  }
```

i get this error :

```
   TS2339 : Property totalPages doesnt exist on type Object
```

how can i resolve this ? thank you in advance .

Comment: Here is all what you need https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response

Comment: thank you @yurzui for help :) i appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Typescript compiler checks that data variable. To fix this explicitly tell TypeScript type of data as any ,

```
this.projetSevice.getProjects(this.currentPage,this.size)
          .subscribe((data:any)=>{
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can be resolved by giving proper type or interface in either return type of your service function like:

```
getProjects(page, size): Observable<MyType>
```

or give type to data obj

```
this.projetSevice.getProjects(this.currentPage,this.size)
      .subscribe(data: MyType=>{
```

and make an interface

```
interface MyType {
    totalPages: number;
    //other properties
}
```

This is for the proper typechecking. There is always an option to use `any` but that is not recommended.